# text from UITextField to UIWebView function

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextfield

I want to add search theWebView for UIWebView, and i need to put search query from UIWebView to the function of button:

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
[theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"%@", searchR];  
}
```

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *theWebView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *searchF;
    IBOutlet UILabel *searchR1;
    NSString *searchR;

    }


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *theWebView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchF;

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SearchWebView.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize theWebView;
@synthesize searchF;

-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [searchF resignFirstResponder];
    searchR = searchF.text;
       searchR1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", searchR];
    /*[theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"%@", searchR];
    [theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"7019"];*/

}

-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender{

    [theWebView removeAllHighlights];

}
```

This is my try, but it don't work!

Help please